# Do managed switches ping on all VLANs by default?

Tags: networking, cisco, hp, switch, ping

Amateur network admin here. I'm trying to create a link via VLAN between a VOIP PBX and an internet router. It's a large installation, so there are 4 managed switches between the two endpoints. I created a VLAN on each switch (3 HPs, 1 Cisco) and set a port on each end switch as `untagged` for that VLAN, plugging the PBX and the router into those two ports respectively. And of course, I marked the traffic on each trunk as `untagged` for the same VLAN.

What I want to know is this: there is another switch on the network that doesn't have this VLAN configured but still manages to ping[1] the router (which has its own specific internal IP). **How is this possible?** Is it passing by the management VLAN to get to the switch where the router is plugged in?

The only rational explanation I can think of is that a switch, when it pings, talks directly to the other switches and then they each ping individually on all their VLANs.

[1] : when say "it pings" I mean that I cannot on the command line to the switch and use it's internal `ping` command.

Answer (score 0):

I would tell the switch used the Trunk to send the ping, didn't tagged the ping packet, and the remote switch received the ping via the Trunk.

You could do a simple packet capture to confirm my theroy with a mirror port on the Trunk.